# Jquery to find which checkbox is checked?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have 10 checkboxes in my page, dynamically created by jquery.

Its starts like **chk1 , chk2 and....so on.**

I want to get which checkbox is checked out of 10 checkboxes .

```
for (i=0; i < tbl01.length; i++)
{
if ($("input[type=checkbox][checked]"))
{
var checked = chk+i;

}
}
```

where

> tbl01

is my dataset to dynamically create my checkboxes

I have tried to some extent, is this correct ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked")
```

Also, if you're just checking whether an element exists, you'll want to check `.length` on the returned selector (because jquery always returns an object, it just might not have anything in it):

```
if ($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: @nandu well it's a bit hard to tell exactly what you're doing, but the ':checked' selector will return any elements that are checked.  I'm not sure what the `for` loop is doing in your code, but the selector inside it is always going to return the same elements.

Comment: oh. Thanks for explaining. I am just a week experienced in jquery and I am struggling with it. even  a single space or colon is making big errors. +1 and answer for you :)

Comment: @nandu if the goal of your `for` loop was to loop through all the checkboxes and find the checked one, that's unnecessary.  The jQuery selector will look at all the checkboxes and find the one that is checked.

Comment: @David do you say that the code works same even without the for loop ? just the if and var chk statement is enough? then thats nice of jquery :)

Comment: @David - After voting you, I got civic duty badge :D

Comment: yes that for loop is redundant and costly since jquery will already scan the DOM and loop trough all the matches, the only thing that worries me here is this will always return one checked box, what happens if you were to check two or more since we know that checkboxes don't behave like radio buttons, then you will have to add the .each() method on top of what @David provided. Hope this helps. Cheers